# Labview Vi's exe File not working via Python script

Tags: labview

I made an exe file of  `labview` project. The vi has a loop for a limited time and vi closes as the loop ends. When I open the exe file by double clicking, the vi opens and runs properly. BUT, if i try to run the exe file using Python script as below, the vi opens and stops at once and loop is not completed.

I have tried multiple python commands to run it, but nothing works. Hope someone knows the solution.

**This is the code**

```
import sys
import os
os.system("C:\\Users\\sjaved\\Desktop\\Pwm_MPC5748G_MT\\BSWs\\MCAL\\Pwm_MPC5748G\\targetTest\\NIPXI\\builds\\NI_Opponent\\Host\\Host.exe")
```

Comment: If the python script is causing the vi to open (even if it doesn't run correctly) I'd be fairly confident that the code is okay. This kind of behavior seems indicative of a Windows permissions issue.

Comment: Would you post your LabVIEW code?

Comment: What happens if you try to run the exe from the Windows command line? Are you sure that the VI exits properly after you've run it by double-clicking?

Comment: Is it just this LabVIEW exe or other exe's (notepad?) as well?

Answer (score 0):

Some older versions of LabVIEW required the "Run when opened" option to be set in your top level VI's Execution preferences in order to auto-run when the app is executed.  I tested this with a LabVIEW 2017 exe and python and the VI ran as expected (even without the "Run when opened" property set).